# SSRS or SQL passing only the first element of a group

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I have the table:

```
Taskname         |Checklist| Start        | End     |Training | StartDT                 | EndDT                   | User    | Answertype
QuizMC1708060531 | QuizMC | 1502033469885 | 1502033478839 | 1 | 2017-08-06 17:31:09.883 | 2017-08-06 17:31:18.837 | adminEn | Multiple
QuizMC1708060531 | QuizMC | 1502033469885 | 1502033478839 | 1 | 2017-08-06 17:31:09.883 | 2017-08-06 17:31:18.837 | adminEn | Text
QuizMC1708060533 | QuizMC | 1502033603938 | 1502033609396 | 1 | 2017-08-06 17:33:23.937 | 2017-08-06 17:33:29.393 | adminEn | Multiple
QuizMC1708060533 | QuizMC | 1502033603938 | 1502033609396 | 1 | 2017-08-06 17:33:23.937 | 2017-08-06 17:33:29.393 | adminEn | Text
QuizMC1708071122 | QuizMC | 1502097788914 | 1502114086923 | 1 | 2017-08-07 11:23:08.913 | 2017-08-07 15:54:46.920 | adminEn | Multiple
QuizMC1708071122 | QuizMC | 1502097788914 | 1502114086923 | 1 | 2017-08-07 11:23:08.913 | 2017-08-07 15:54:46.920 | adminEn | Text
QuizMC1708070354 | QuizMC | 1502114092033 | 1502173089869 | 1 | 2017-08-07 15:54:52.030 | 2017-08-08 08:18:09.867 | adminEn | Multiple
QuizMC1708070354 | QuizMC | 1502114092033 | 1502173089869 | 1 | 2017-08-07 15:54:52.030 | 2017-08-08 08:18:09.867 | adminEn | Text
```

So I would like to (Either through SQL or SSRS) group all the entries by Taskname so that per task name only one entry exists. In this case it means that every second row will be discarded. This table can differ in size, meaning that one Taskname group could have 1 entry, 2, 5, 10. It does not matter to me which row I get it only matters that there is only one row per group.

EDIT: I mustn't loose any rows, adding new rows is okay.

Comment: How do you determine which row is 1st and which is second whithin a group? Or you can take any row?

Comment: Any row  will do.

Comment: Due to the fact that is is/was a looooonnnngggg work day. :) Removed the mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query as below:

```
Select top(1) with ties * from yourtable
   order by row_number() over (partition by TaskName order by startDt)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT Taskname  ,Checklist, Start ,End,Training, StartDT, EndDT, User , Answertype 
FROM
(
SELECT Taskname  ,Checklist, Start ,End,Training, StartDT, EndDT, User , Answertype ,
ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PArtition by Taskname ORder by StartDT DESC) AS Dup
FROm YourTable
)
DT WHERE dt.Dup=1
```

Comment: I have changed it a bit, because of the keywords, to: SELECT Taskname  ,Checklist, Start ,[End],Training, StartDT, EndDT, User , Answertype 
     FROM
     (
     SELECT Taskname  ,Checklist, Start ,[End],Training, StartDT, EndDT, User , Answertype ,
     ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PArtition by Taskname ORder by StartDT DESC) AS Dup
     FROm @MyTable
     )
     dt WHERE dt.Dup=1     but the code can not resolve the DT (DT WHERE dt.dump=1)